# Unexpected behavior for stderr redirection in bash

Tags: bash, shell, sh

My understanding of stdout/stderr is that a script can log to stderr, and produce 'useful' output in stdout, which will be piped or captured by the calling process if needed.

In practice, this doesn't work the way I thought it would.

```
➜ cat test.sh 
echo diagnostic blah blah 1>&2
echo result
```

My understanding is that if I do `echo $(./test.sh)`, I should just get 'result', since 'diagnostic blah blah' was sent to stderr. However, I get:

```
➜ echo $(./test.sh)            
diagnostic blah blah
result
```

This works correctly which shows that the redirection to stderr is actually working:

```
➜ echo $(./test.sh 2>/dev/null) 
result
```

So I guess my understanding of how output is processed in shell scripts is wrong. What am I missing?

As another example, I wouldn't expect this to work:

```
➜ ./test.sh | grep diagnostic
diagnostic blah blah
```

Comment: How do you expect to be able to tell tell which of this content is captured by the process substitution and subsequently emitted by `echo` and which is going direct to your TTY via stderr? The end destination is the TTY both ways, after all.

Comment: good point - will edit to demonstrate.

Comment: The pipe to grep is just coincidence, you could pipe to anything and it will display `diagnostic blah blah`, since stderr is being sent to the TTY instead of through the pipe.

Comment: ^ yep
`➜ ./test.sh | grep anything-at-all`

`diagnostic blah blah`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test process doesn't provide any means of distinguishing between stdout and stderr. Consider instead:

```
echo "stderr only here:"
result=$(./test.sh)      ## stderr goes straight to TTY, stdout gets captured
echo
echo "writing the previously-captured stdout:"
printf '%s\n' "$result"  ## printf is better-defined than echo
```

Answer (score 0):

Charles Duffy is right - the test.sh script works as expected.

The root cause of the initial problem I was investigating is simpler - I was redirecting all log outputs from my script to `stderr`, but I was not redirecting output from additional commands in the script (in my case `pip install ...`)